# How to prevent Google from crawling partial url found in javascript?

Tags: javascript, seo, google-search-console

I have recently added a site to Google Search Console and a lot of 404 errors are showing, all with the same pattern :

```
https://example.com/metas?some_id=247
```

That page does not exists and is linked to anywhere on the site. But I when check the source code fo the page that is to be the referer, I have a script tag with this code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/products/" + productId + "/metas?some_id=247",
  dataType: 'script',
  success: function(data) {
    // ...
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Why would Google bot crawl this url and how I can I prevent this from happening (obviously `rel="nofollow"` is out of the question here)? Would it help to put the script in a external .js file instead instead of a `<script>` tag in the page html code?

Comment: Externalising and blocking that dir in robots.txt would for sure help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Answer (score 3):

It is generally considered a good idea to apply a `noindex` tag on URLs that don't exist.

Depending on your platform, simply edit your 404 page template to include `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />` to solve a lot of issues.

For tricky automatically generated URLs due to a script, plugin or whatever you can use a URL pattern match to apply your noindex tag.

Here is an example in PHP:

```html
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url,'YOURQUERY') !== false) {
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> '
}
```